# Quick question: can the marginalization of an operator be seen as the functional calculus of a function?

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-calculus

Since for projectors $\lbrace P_\alpha \rbrace_{\alpha} $  and  $\lbrace Q_\beta \rbrace_{\beta} $ on a hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ that are each a partition of unity:

$$\sum_\alpha P_\alpha Q_\beta = Q_\beta$$
$$\sum_\beta P_\alpha Q_\beta = P_\alpha$$

is there a function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and a function $g:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  such that their functional calculus is such that:

$$f(P_\alpha Q_\beta) = \sum_\alpha P_\alpha Q_\beta = Q_\beta$$
$$g(P_\alpha Q_\beta) = \sum_\beta P_\alpha Q_\beta = P_\alpha$$

If so, which functions are these?
I am trying to prove the easier version of the proposition that for every element $M$ of a context $\mathcal{C}$ there is a generating element of this context $\widetilde{M}$ and a real function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that: $f(\widetilde{M})= M$.
But considering only projectors, and not making mention to this generating element the context $\widetilde{M}$.